# Trying to implement my movement with left down right and up arrow keys for 15 puzzle game

Tags: javascript, sliding-tile-puzzle

I need help with fixing my movement code.  I am not so javascript friendly. I am just using the old fashion table technique and javascript.  I cannot use any jquery or other sources. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border:  solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

td {
    width: 20px;

}


</style>


<script>

var bposr =3; // blank position : row
var bposc=3;  // blank position : column


function keypress() {
var ieKey = event.keyCode;



     if (ieKey == 40 && bposr!=0){ // for moving down
        temp= document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr-1].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr-1].cells[bposc].innerHTML=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML=temp;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor='#DCDCDC';
       document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr-1].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';
        bposr--;
   }

    else if (ieKey == 37 && bposc!=1){  // for moving right
        temp= document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1].innerHTML=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML=temp;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor='#DCDCDC';
       document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1].style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';
        bposc++;

    }

    else if (ieKey == 39 && bposc!=1){  // for moving left
        temp= document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1].innerHTML=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML=temp;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor='#DCDCDC';
       document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1].style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';
        bposc++;

    }

else if (ieKey == 38 && bposr!=0){ // for moving down
        temp= document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr-1].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr-1].cells[bposc].innerHTML=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML=temp;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor='#DCDCDC';
       document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr-1].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';
        bposr--;
   }

}

function start(){
                document.onkeydown = keypress;
                }
</script>

</head>


<body onLoad="start()">
<center>
<table id="myTable">


  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td style="background-color:white;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error ? What is it supposed to do ?

Comment: I need the empty white block to be able to move around the order and I am trying to start it randomized and you win at that state the numbers are set in. I am just having trouble setting up the boundaries for when it hits the wall. So, for instance, if I press left key it will make the empty block go left and it pushes the left block in the empty blocks previous position.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering how would I start going about starting off the game with the number tiles randomized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some logic errors in the movement conditions, besides that your code works just fine.

```js
var Table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var bposr =3; // blank position : row
var bposc=3;  // blank position : column

function keypress(ieKey) {

 var ieKey = event.keyCode;

 var Table = document.getElementById("myTable");

 console.log(Table);

 console.log(ieKey);

 if (ieKey == 40 && bposr != 0){ // for moving down

  console.log(bposr);

  temp = Table.rows[bposr - 1].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
  Table.rows[bposr - 1].cells[bposc].innerHTML = Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
  Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML = temp;
  Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor = '#DCDCDC';
  Table.rows[bposr - 1].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
  bposr--;

 } else if (ieKey == 39 && bposc != 0){  // for moving right

  console.log(bposc);

  temp = Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc - 1].innerHTML;
    Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc - 1].innerHTML = Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
    Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML = temp;
    Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor = '#DCDCDC';
    Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc - 1].style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    bposc--;

 } else if (ieKey == 37 && bposc != 3){  // for moving left

  console.log(bposc);

  temp = Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc + 1].innerHTML;
    Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc + 1].innerHTML = Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
    Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML = temp;
    Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor = '#DCDCDC';
    Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc + 1].style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    bposc++;

 } else if (ieKey == 38 && bposr != 3){ // for moving up

  console.log(bposr);

  temp = Table.rows[bposr + 1].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
  Table.rows[bposr + 1].cells[bposc].innerHTML = Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
  Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML = temp;
  Table.rows[bposr].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor = '#DCDCDC';
  Table.rows[bposr + 1].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
  bposr++;

  }

}

function start(){
 document.onkeydown = keypress;
}
```

```css
table, td {
  border:  solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

td {
  width: 20px;

}
```

```html
<center>
<table id="myTable">


 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>

  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td style="background-color:white;"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<br>
</center>
```

Comment: For the question you commented in the question (I can't reply for obvius reasons), you can use Math.Random() to do it. But that doesn't guarantees that the combination given can be solved. Here is how I did it: http://codepen.io/vrpg1998/pen/dWPXWy

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the randomize code. I will see if it is beatable before I finish it.